# Rails, Active admin, nested form, dynamic label value - issue with the form object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, nested-forms

I have three models:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scenario
  belongs_to :location

  has_many :actions, :foreign_key => 'request_id'
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :actions, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :request
  belongs_to :scenario_step
end

class ScenarioStep < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scenario
  has_many :actions
end
```

Using Active Admin I want to update information about action taken in response to a request. To do that I am using nested form:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Request do

    permit_params :scenario_id, :location_id, 
                actions_attributes: [:scenario_step_id, :description]


     form(:html => {:multipart => true}) do |f|
      f.inputs "Request details" do
        f.input :status

        panel 'Steps' do
         "Text ..."
        end
        f.has_many :actions, heading: 'Steps to follow', allow_destroy: false, new_record: true do |ff|
            ff.input :description, label: ff.object.scenario_step_id, hint: 'Text'
            ff.input :scenario_step_id

          end

        para "Press cancel to return to the list without saving."
        f.actions

      end
    end
end
```

Everything seems to be fine except of label (or hint). As a value I want to put there related data from a table scenario_steps.

As you can see I currently try to at least print the value of scenario_step_id that should be available in the object form (ff.object.scenario_step_id) but it is not working (I have such column in actions table). On the other hand, next line: ff.input :scenario_step_id loads appropriate data into input field.

Can somebody give ma a hint what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I was missing (part of formtastic documentation):

> Values for labels/hints/actions are can take values: String (explicit
>   value), Symbol (i18n-lookup-key relative to the current "type", e.g.
>   actions:), true (force I18n lookup), false (force no I18n lookup).
>   Titles (legends) can only take: String and Symbol - true/false have no
>   meaning.

So small change (to_s) in line below makes huge difference :)

```
 ff.input :description, label: ff.object.scenario_step_id.to_s, hint: 'Text'
```